# Pass a variable into a for loop -- not working

Tags: jekyll

I'm trying to pass an argument into a liquid filter in a `for` loop, but I can't get it to work.

In `_data`, I have a file called `fruit_metadata.yml` with this content:

```
apples:
  country: unites states

bananas:
  country: brazil

oranges:
  country: florida
```

I want to loop through the content and get the country for each fruit. Here's what i'm doing:

````
{% assign fruit = "apples, oranges, bananas" | split: "," %}
{% for item in fruit %}
* doesn't work: {{ site.data.fruit_metadata[item].country }}
* works: {{ site.data.fruit_metadata.apples.country }}
{% endfor %}```

For some reason, `[item]` doesn't seem to be working. The "doesn't work" line returns nothing. The "works" line returns "united states."

How can I pass in `item` here to get the data?
````

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed to remove the spaces in `apples,oranges,bananas`.